# Module 'Magento_MsrpSampleData': [ERROR] while reinstalling magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions

Getting error while installing

```
Module 'Magento_MsrpSampleData':
[ERROR] Magento\Framework\Setup\Exception: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly. in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier.php:167
Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(1002): Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier->applyDataPatch('Magento_MsrpSam...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(874): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data', Array) #2 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(367): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #6 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #11 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\setup\index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #16 {main}
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please let me know what is the php version you are running on ? Also let me know the Exact Magento version.

Comment: php7.2.3 and Apache server, Magento 2

Comment: Could you please keep your var/log/system.log  open during installation and check there should be one more error like "main.ERROR: Sample Data error" above the "main.ERROR: Unable to apply data patch " please provide that exact error.

Comment: in System.log file : main.ERROR: Sample Data error: URL key for specified store already exists. [] []